# Raspberry pi won't boot when booting with LIDAR connected to raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, ros, gpio, lidar

This question was helped by a translator.

I'm currently installing Ubuntu 18.04, ROS Melodic on Raspberry Pi 3B+.

However, if you boot the Raspberry Pi with LD06 LIDAR connected, it will not boot.

Raspberry Pi and LD06 Lidar are connected to pin 4 (5V), pin 6 (GND), pin 10 (GPIO 15, RXD), and pin 12 (GPIO 18, PWM).

Is there a reason to have problems if I boot with those pins connected?

LD06 LIDAR Specifications
https://www.okdo.com/p/okdo-lidar-module-with-bracket/

Comment: Could it be that the Lidar is sucking too much power? What's its power rating? Also, how are you powering your Pi, how many Amps are you providing?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply.

I'm not sure what you're talking about AMP.

According to the data sheet of LD06 : 
Input Voltage - 4.5~5.5V / Start up Current - 300mA / Work Current - 180mA.
And the two power supplies I use for Raspberry Pi 3B+
The first one : Rated input: 220V 60Hz, 0.35A / Rated output: 5V, 2.4A
The second one : Rated input: 220V 60Hz, 0.35A /  Rated output: 5V, 3.0A

Comment: 3Amps should be enough if the lidar only draws a max of 0.3A of that. So I guess that's not the problem. The next thing I'd double check is that you are connecting to the right pins and not, accidentally, shortening the Pi.

Comment: I double checked all connections and found that they are all connected correctly. It's very mysterious.

Comment: I think we've found the cause. In the initial U-Boot phase, the LiDAR scan signal input to GPIO 15 (RXD) was recognized as a command input and could not exit the U-Boot phase.